# Why are these errors showing up?

Tags: python

This is a simple program to encrypt a string into simple cipher text, but I keep getting error messages. Can someone find my mistake? Attached below are the code and error messages.

```
def main():
    message = prep_plaintext(plaintext)
    rails = build_rails(message)
    encrypt(rails)

def prep_plaintext(plaintext):
    message = "".join(plaintext.split())
    message = message.upper()
    print("\nplaintext = {}".format(plaintext))
    return message

def build_rails(message):
    evens = message[::2]
    odds = message[1::2]
    rails = evens + odds
    return rails

def encrypt(rails):
    ciphertext = ' '.join([rails[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(rails), 5)])
    print("ciphertext = {}".format(ciphertext))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bennettsullivan/Documents/Encrypt.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/bennettsullivan/Documents/Encrypt.py", line 2, in main
    message = prep_plaintext(plaintext)
NameError: name 'plaintext' is not defined
```

Comment: in `prep_plaintext(plaintext)` where does `plaintext` comes ? An input from the user ? That is the error

Comment: `plaintext` is a parameter of `pre_plaintext`, not a global variable or local variable in`main`.

Comment: On line 23 you call function `main()`. `main()` kicks off and calls `prep_plaintext(plaintext)` but at this point in the program `plaintext` hasn't been defined. In other words on Line 2, you are saying *"pass what is stored in the variable `plaintext` to the function `prep_plaintext()`"* yet there is nothing stored in `plaintext` to pass to `prep_plaintext()`

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot I needed to define plaintext, thanks!

Comment: @Pythoncoder please if one answer solved your problem, mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem

In `message = prep_plaintext(plaintext)`, the variable `plaintext` is defined nowhere

#### Solution

1. Define the variable in the method

   ```py
   def main():
       plaintext = "password"
       message = prep_plaintext(plaintext)
   ```
2. Pass it as a parameter

   ```py
   def main(plaintext):
       message = prep_plaintext(plaintext)

   main("password")
   ```

#### Improve with user input

You can also replace `"password"` by `input("Please enter a value to encrypt: ")` to write a word in the console at code execution

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the variable *plaintext* in the main function that it's not declared. For this reason this code raises an error.

You can fix for example modifying you code like this:

```
def main():
    plaintext = ""  # put here a value
    message = prep_plaintext(plaintext)
    rails = build_rails(message)
    encrypt(rails)
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is the cause, the variable `plaintext` is not defined in `main()`

```py
    message = prep_plaintext(plaintext)
```

Maybe try `message = prep_plaintext(input('plaintext: '))`
or change

```py
def main():
```

to

```
def main(plaintext):
```

and give a parameter to `main()`